# How can I unfreeze a frozen chat room?

Tags: support

How can I "defrost" a chat room that has been "automatically frozen because of inactivity"? It has long been my desire to respond in this [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3479/conversation-between-jas-3-1-and-brilliant), but various circumstances in my life didn't allow me to do that. Partly the reason for my procrastination here was the fact that I was unaware of such policy on this website - I never thought that a chat room could be possibly frozen and later even deleted. So what should I do now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You poke a moderator, either here on meta or by pinging anybody who happens to the in the main [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). I just [unfroze your room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6091231#6091231).

In fact, you can ping anybody in chat who is a moderator on ANY site not just C.SE as chat moderation privileges are network-wide. Besides your regular C.SE moderators, [Jon Ericson](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/914/jon-ericson) for example is a frequent visitor to our chat room and could fix you up.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: @brilliant: I nearly always have a tab open to several of my favorite chat rooms, including the Upper Room and the Library, so you can find me there.  _Apropos_ of nothing, is it odd that your handle reminds me of those [Guinness ads](http://www.youtube.com/watch?&v=oHNMg_U9vgo)?  ;-)

Comment: @JonEricson "I nearly always have a tab open to several of my favorite chat rooms" - If I am the only one in that room and I am keeping it opened on one of my browser's tabs, yet not writing any post in it, will the room still be considered as inactive?

Comment: @JonEricson - "Apropos of nothing, is it odd that your handle reminds me of those Guinness ads? ;-)" - HA-HA!!! Well, there's nothing wrong about this association, however, my handle is a noun. The one on the ad is an adjective.

Comment: @brilliant: You have to post _something_ in order for a room to stay thawed.  Just going to a room doesn't keep it warm.

Comment: @brilliant: Rooms don't freeze until quite a long period of dis-use. Weeks I think. Don't worry about keeping anything open, just use it like you're going to use it and if something gets frozen that you want to use, let us know.

Comment: Wow. American Guinness advertising is *weird*, @JonEricson. Never seen anything like that before.